# What is freezer burn?

Tags: meat

What causes freezer burn?

How can I tell if meat has freezer burn?

Comment: See [this question](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/16769/5505) for an example of freezer burn.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Freezer burn is just the food being dehydrated.  Most meat will change color, and it becomes very obvious if you defrost it.  It's not unsafe:  just yucky.

Comment: If it's just dehydrating it, why can't you just add water back in (eg. cook/soak it in liquid)?

Comment: @DoubleAA no you can't. The surface gets dehidrated, its texture changes in an  irreversible way.

Answer (score 3):

Leaving foods unwrapped or directly exposed to the air in your freezer/refridgerator will contribute greatly to freezer burn - try to put leftovers in containers or wrap them to ward against freezer burn :)